# Como recibir los valores de un Json (Ajax) en un controlador Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, json

Hola tengo este código en el cual envió mis datos de una tabla a un json para después insertarlos pero cuando ya los envió no encuentro la manera para recibirlos y extraerlos

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#enviar').on('click', function() {


     var fecha = $("#fecha").val();  
     var operador = $("#idmip").val();
     var captura = $("#captura").val();
     var filas = [];
    $('#table-1 tbody tr').each(function() {
      var codigo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
      var mono = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      var lineitem = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      var pn = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
      var ordenado = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text();
      var pcspkg = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
      var operation = $(this).find('td').eq(6).text();
      var otiempo = $(this).find('td').eq(7).text();

      var fila = {
        codigo,
        mono,
        lineitem,
        pn,
        ordenado,
        pcspkg,
        operation,
        otiempo
      };
      filas.push(fila);
    });


   $.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "{{URL::to('store')}}",
  data: {valores : JSON.stringify(filas)},

  success: function(data) { 
    alert("Todo  Bien") //mensaje de envio correcto
     }
   });

  });
});


</script>
```

El codigo de mi controlador en donde se supone recibo los datos es el siguiente..

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
// este metodo obtiene el json y se lo asigna a la variable $datos
$datos = $request->json()->all();;
///valida que sea un peticion ajax
if($request->ajax()){
$datos->valores;
}

}
```

si los recibo pero no se como extraer cada dato de las tablas

Adjunto una captura de lo que me devuelve el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Angel, no se mucho de laravel pero ¿podrias imprimir y mostrar lo que retorna la variable $data?
de esta manera es posible que se pueda resolver algo...

Comment: Hola @JDavid al hacer una impresión de data con dd() solo me da respuesta "True" supongo que esto marca que si hay recepción de datos

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví con el siguiente código en mi controlador

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $array = $request->valores; //valores es el array que envió con el ajax
    $array = json_decode($array);



    $max=sizeof($array);  //Me devuelve el tamaño del array

    $fecha = $array[0]->fecha; // la fecha de mi posición 0 en el array
   }
```

Comment: Por favor considera explicar tu código, recuerda que tu respuesta no solo debe ser comprensible para ti, sino para el resto de la comunidad también

Comment: @Aprendiz entendido, completare mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      // este metodo obtiene el json y se lo asigna a la variable $datos
      $datos = $request->json();
      // o tambien puedes hacer:
      $datos = $request->json()->all();
      ///valida que sea un peticion ajax
      if($request->ajax()){
          echo $datos->valores;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, ya probé tu solución pero ahora obtengo este mensaje de error
{message: "Trying to get property 'codigo' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Comment: Sorry ya coregi no vi tu ajax

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta y agregue tu código con una captura del error que arroja